# Como alinhar um texto em uma div?

Tags: html, div, text, css

Hoje *(03/01/2023)*, estava fazendo meu primeiro site pessoal usando HTML e CSS.

Inicialmente criei uma série de divs em uma mesma linha, entretanto ao inserir um **texto** dentro de uma das divs o mesmo **ficava alinhado verticalmente no fim do container** como mostrado na imagem a seguir

[[image: Imagem com o suposto BUG]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLIYS.png)

Nessa imagem percebemos que a `div` em verde sairia da linha, mesmo todos os divs se tratando de `inline-blocks` os quais deveriam ficar em sequência. Como resolver tal situação?

Answer (score -2):

Achei uma solução para a minha situação!

Utilizando a propriedade do **CSS** `vertical-align: text-bottom;`  dentro da div em **verde** a qual estava bugada resolve a situação por completo.

Não achei muito conteúdo sobre por isso decidi postar aqui.

[[image: Imagem do Problema resolvido]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLbbm.png)